# Select data from each previous months - MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I want to generate graph like this.

[image]

I need data like this to generate graph like above.

```
June - Art 2
June - Commerce 4
June - Maths 4
June - Science 5

May - Art 2
May - Commerce 3
May - Maths 4
May - Science 4
```

I tried this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT (
MONTHNAME( user_reg )
), u.sec_name, u.count
FROM (

SELECT COUNT( user_section ) AS count, sections.sec_name, users.user_reg
FROM users
LEFT JOIN sections ON users.user_section = sections.sec_id
GROUP BY sections.sec_name
) AS u
```

Result was

[image]

Table structure for **users** table

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(u.user_reg), s.sec_name, COUNT(*)
FROM users u JOIN
     sections s
     ON u.user_section = s.sec_id
GROUP BY MONTHNAME(u.user_reg), s.sec_name
ORDER BY MIN(u.user_reg), s.sec_name;
```

Some notes:

- You don't seem to need the `left join`.  If something doesn't match, you don't want it counted.
- This introduces table aliases as abbreviates for the table names, making the query easier to read and write.
- This has an explicit `ORDER BY` so the results are in a reasonable order for the chart.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you don't need to subquery, simply join the tables, count the sections and group by section name and  month name:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT( u.user_section ) AS count, 
  s.sec_name, 
  u.user_reg,
  MONTHNAME(u.user_reg)
FROM users u
JOIN sections s ON u.user_section = s.sec_id
GROUP BY 
  s.sec_name,
  MONTHNAME(u.user_reg)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Both your query working properly and match for the my situation. Unfortunately i can't mark both answers as answers.